# Android 5+ File saved "incorrect"

Tags: java, android, storage, record, voice

I wrote a small Android App to record audio and save this on the disk of the smartphone. Now I've got the problem that it's saved on the wrong location with the wrong name and I can't see why. (I'm relative new to Android programming)

```
public void startRecording(View view) {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + R.string.app_name);
    file_name = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + R.string.app_name;

    if(!folder.exists()) {
        boolean created = folder.mkdirs();
        if(!created) { Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Could not create folder/s."); return; }
    }

    if(editText.getText() != null)
        file_name += editText.getText() + ".3gp";
    else
        file_name += Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + ".3gp";

    outputFile = new File(file_name);

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file_name);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);

    Toast.makeText(CaptureActivity.this, R.string.toast_recording_start, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        Toast.makeText(CaptureActivity.this, R.string.toast_recording_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mediaRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

The file should be saved in a folder called TrueCapture and the file itself should be called ggj.3gp .
But the file is saved on the internal storage under the name 2131099680ggj.3gp .
The next problem there is, I can only find the file with the explorer app from my smartphone. The PC can't find the file and no other app.

---

Some Details:

- Android 6
- File Name is wrong (2131099680ggj.3gp instead of ggj.3gp)
- File is saved in internal storage in no specific folder instead of the external storage (SD card is in the smartphone) in a new folder called "TrueCapture"
- No other app seems to know about this file except for the explorer app of the smartphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.string.app_name` is the ID assigned to your resource in the `R` class, an `int`.

To get your `String` resource, you might wanna use the `getString()` method of `Context`.

Something like this should work:

```
String ext = ".3gp";

File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name));
if(!folder.exists()) {
    folder.mkdirs();
}

file_name = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/";

if(editText.getText().length() > 0) {
    file_name += editText.getText().toString() + ext;
} else {
    file_name += Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ext;
}

File outputFile = new File(file_name);

// ...
```

You also need to add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```